# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet

Tags: spring-mvc, google-app-engine, java-8, backend

I am getting this error while deploying a new version. 
Build tool: gradle

Although the same code with a different version that was deployed some time back is working well. The exceptions are as below. On local env code is working fine.

```
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder doStart:  (BaseHolder.java:101)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApplicationClassLoader.findClass(ApplicationClassLoader.java:135)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:891)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.startWebapp(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doStart(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:240)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:178)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:120)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:747)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:710)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:680)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:872)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:270)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

build.gradle file is as below: I am sharing the main module file. Other build.gradle file are just the supporting files.

```
/*
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'com.google.http-client'
}
*/

configurations.runtime {
    exclude group: 'com.ibm.websphere', module: 'uow'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.geronimo.specs', module: 'geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec'
    exclude group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'jsp-api'
    exclude group: 'com.sun', module: 'tools'
    exclude group: 'ant', module: 'ant'
    exclude group: 'com.wadpam', module: 'docrest-doclet'
    exclude group: 'com.wadpam', module: 'docrest-api'
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.goldengekko:user-service:1.0.5') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('com.goldengekko:security-support:1.0.2') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:3.0'
    compile("com.goldengekko:user-security-mgmt:2.1.112") {
        //exclude module: 'appengine-gcs-client'
        exclude module: 'docrest-doclet'
        exclude module: 'commons-dbcp'
        exclude module: 'spring-jdbc'
        exclude module: 'log4j'
        exclude group: 'javax.mail', module: 'mail'
        exclude module: "geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec"
        exclude group: "javax.activation", module: "activation"
        exclude group: "javax.servlet", module: "servlet-api"
        exclude group: 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client'
        exclude group: 'com.google.http-client', module: 'google-http-client-jackson2'
        exclude group: 'com.goldengekko', module: 'gae-support'
        //changing = true //for snapshot
    }

    compile('com.goldengekko:gae-support:2.0.24') {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: 'com.goldengekko', module: 'core-server'
        exclude group: 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client'
        exclude group: 'com.google.http-client', module: 'google-http-client-jackson2'
        exclude group: 'com.google.appengine.tools', module: 'appengine-gcs-client'
    }

    compile('com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.5') {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: 'com.google.http-client', module: 'google-http-client-jackson2'
        exclude group: 'com.google.api-client', module: 'google-api-client-appengine'
    }

    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-appengine:1.23.0')

    compile ('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.19.0')
    compile ('com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.19.0')
    compile ('com.google.code.gson:gson:1.5')
    compile('net.sf.mardao:mardao-gae:2.3.3') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile('com.goldengekko:core-server:1.0.57') {
        transitive = true
    }

    runtime 'org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:1.1.0.M1'

    compile ('com.goldengekko:crud-support:1.0.2') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile ('com.goldengekko.android:networking:1.9') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.goldengekko:mobile-push-support:1.1.7') {
        transitive = false
    }

    compile('com.wadpam.gaelic:gaelic-oauth2-provider:1.0.8') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('com.wadpam.gaelic:gaelic-domain:1.0.8') {
        transitive = true
    }a
    compile ('com.wadpam.gaelic:gaelic-appengine:1.0.8') {
        transitive = true
    }

    /*
    compile ('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.4') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.4') {
        transitive = true
    } */

    runtime ('cglib:cglib:2.2.2') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.60') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:1.9.60') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.1'
    //providedCompile('javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5') { transitive=false}
    compile('org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.9.RELEASE') {
        force = true
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.9.RELEASE') {
        force = true
        transitive = false
    }
    compile ('commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6') {
        force = true
        transitive = false
    }

    compile ('org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.9.RELEASE') {
        force = true
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('com.ibm.websphere:com.springsource.com.ibm.websphere.uow:6.0.2.17') {
        force = true
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('org.springframework:spring-oxm:4.0.9.RELEASE') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('org.apache.axis:axis:1.4') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:1.1') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('commons-discovery:commons-discovery:0.4') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.2') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:1.6.2') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.7.2') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('commons-io:commons-io:2.4') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile ('commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'org.osgeo:proj4j:0.1.0'
    compile 'uk.co.jemos.podam:podam:3.3.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.2'
    compile 'org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:1.5.9'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:1.10.26'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.6.3'

    runtime ('org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:1.1.0.M1') {
        transitive = true
    }

    runtime('org.springframework.social:spring-social-salesforce:1.0') {
        transitive = true
    }

    runtime('com.goldengekko.social:spring-social-gaelic:1.0')
    runtime('com.goldengekko:core-domain:1.0.3')

    runtime('org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:1.1.4.RELEASE') {
        transitive = true
    }
    runtime('org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:1.1.1.RELEASE') {
        transitive = true
    }
    runtime('org.springframework.social:spring-social-google:1.0.0.M2') {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: 'com.google.http-client', module: 'google-http-client'
        exclude group: 'com.google.http-client', module: 'google-http-client-jackson2'
    }

    compileOnly 'com.goldengekko:docrest-doclet:3.0.7'

    compile 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.0'

    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'

}
```

Comment: Which version of the App Engine SDK for Java are you using? can you share the build.gradle as this error sounds to be because of missing the dependencies on it.

Comment: com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.60

Comment: GAE sdk was discontinued. I have updated the version and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the old SDK,

[here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download) you can download the most updated version of it.